# Animate View Movement for OS X app using Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, animation

I have two scroll views, one of them with constraints that make it take up the full parent view, and the other right next to it, but hidden outside the bounds of the parent view. I want to animate both sliding left until the second scroll view takes up the full parent view, and the first scroll view is now out of bounds on the left. How do I do this for an OS X app using Swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured this one out with a little hunting and piecing things together.

Create an IBOutlet for the constraints that you want to change in the animation. In this case, use the leading constraint for each scroll view.

```
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollView1LeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollView2LeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then, use the following:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in
    context.duration = //length of the animation time in seconds
    self. ScrollView1LeadingConstraint.animator().constant = //negative width of scroll view
    self.ScrollView2LeadingConstraint.animator().constant = 0
}, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
    //insert any completion code here
})
```

This will animate the first scroll view out of frame on the left, and move the second scroll view into its former place.