# Animate the position of a Window. Swift and macOS

Tags: swift, macos

How can I animate the position of a window with Swift, macOS, Storyboard.

What I have tried:

```
@IBAction func move(_ sender: NSButton) {
    NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
      context.duration = 2.0
        self.view.window?.setFrame(NSRect(x:50,y:50,
                                          width:200,
                                          height:300),
                                   display: true)
    })
}
```

This works well to move it. But it jumps and I try to make it animate. Is it possible?

Comment: Hey, take a look at this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-start-an-animation-immediately-after-a-view-appears

Comment: @LoVo. that is for Swift UI. I am looking for storyboard and macOS. Thank you anyway

Comment: Oh sry, how about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111550/animate-view-movement-for-os-x-app-using-swift/38112976

Comment: This is very similar to the code that I provide. It works to animate an element inside a window. It seems it do not work to animate the whole window.